# Displaying Image in Circle in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, performance, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am creating a WP (7.1+8) app, that requires me to display images inside a circle ( as in Google+ ).
I found a solution that uses a GradientBrush to accomplish the task via following code:-

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("http://url-of-the-image", UriKind.Absolute);
image.CacheMode = new BitmapCache();
image.Source = bitmapImage;
image.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
image.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;

//Setting up the mask
RadialGradientBrush opacityMask = new RadialGradientBrush();
GradientStop gs1 = new GradientStop();
GradientStop gs2 = new GradientStop();
GradientStop gs3 = new GradientStop();
gs1.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0);
gs1.Offset = 0.0;
gs2.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0);
gs2.Offset = 0.999;
gs3.Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
gs3.Offset = 1.0;
opacityMask.GradientStops.Add(gs1);
opacityMask.GradientStops.Add(gs2);
opacityMask.GradientStops.Add(gs3);
image.OpacityMask = opacityMask;
```

I want to know that what will be the **performance** impact if i needed to do this on large number of images, say 50.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use clipping to display partial area of a control.

```
<Image Source="YouImage.jpg">
    <Image.Clip>
        <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" />
    </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

Change the Center, RadiusX and RadiusY to your convenience.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code snippet for your requirement.

```
<Ellipse Height="300" Width="300">
       <Ellipse.Fill>
             <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/WmDev.jpg" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center" />
       </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

Hope it Helps.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this method too, to compare for performance.

Comment: Sure Vikas, you can try any time.

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered still if you want to see it in more detail then you could have a look [here](http://www.maskaravivek.com/windows-phone/displaying-circular-image-in-windows-phone-app/)
The XAML solution will be,

```
    <Image Source=”{Binding Converter={StaticResource ContactPictureConverter}}” Width=”48″ Height=”48″ Stretch=”Fill”
>

<Image.Clip>

<EllipseGeometry Center=”24,24″ RadiusX=”24″ RadiusY=”24″ />

</Image.Clip>

</Image>
```